# Segmentation fault when i try to NULL pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

I got segmentation fault error in debugger when code rey to NULL pointer.

This function do error :

```
void Player::nullActive()
{
    activeCharacter = NULL;
}
```

activeCharacter is just a pointer of Character class.

Also, here is player class :

```
class Player
{
    public:
        Player(unsigned int accID, std::string aID, bool isBanned); //constructor, allow only create object id-s one time
        ~Player();

        std::string getAtheriusID(); //return account id

        unsigned int getAccountID(); //return atherius id

        boost::ptr_vector<Character> characters;

        bool isBanned();

        bool hasActiveCharacter();

        void nullActive();

        void setActiveCharacter(Character * character);

        void setConnection(CSConnection * con);
        CSConnection * getConnection();

        Character * getActiveCharacter();

        unsigned int atheriusCoins;
    protected:
        unsigned int accountID; //account unique id
        std::string atheriusID; //account name / atherius id
        bool banned;

    private:
        CSConnection * connection;
        Character * activeCharacter = NULL;
};
```

And output of debugger :

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. At
>   F:\EternalHeroes\server\src\game\src\Player.cpp:36 Continuing...
>   Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. At
>   F:\EternalHeroes\server\src\game\src\Player.cpp:36 Continuing...
>   [Inferior 1 (process 11552) exited with code 030000000005] Debugger
>   finished with status 0

Comment: Not enough info, what's `Character` class ? Do you mean `char *activeCharacter ;` ?

Comment: There's no way that can give you a segfault without some other undefined behaviour going on (unless `operator=` for that type does something stupid).

Comment: As much as I can guess by this much info, `activeCharacter` is a member variable and by the time this function is executed `this` pointer is damaged/nulled.

Comment: It's probably what happened *after* you made it a null pointer.

Comment: Added Player class and debugger output.

Comment: and `Player.cpp:36` is that assignment?

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker yes, 36 line nulls activecharacter.

Comment: @KacperFałat, then I think `this` is corrupt/null when `nullActive()` is executed.

Comment: Like `Player *x = NULL; x->nullActive()`.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker thanks, i will check that option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just moving it from comment to the answer, since it's not very likely there will be any other ;)

As much as I can guess by this much info, activeCharacter is a member variable and by the time this function is executed this pointer is damaged/nulled.